# Cannot call WCF service methods from php script

Tags: php, wcf

I have WCF service.
When I try to access it from .NET page all works fine. However I cannot find a way to access it from php script.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0">
      <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="01:00:00" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>

    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RegisterBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="48" maxConcurrentSessions="5000"
        maxConcurrentInstances="5000" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="..."
          cacheLogonTokens="true" cachedLogonTokenLifetime="01:00:00" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="RegisterBehavior" name="Riepas.WCFRiepas">
    <endpoint address="..."
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="...">

    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="mex"
      contract="IMetadataExchange">

    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
 />
```

Tried connecting from php, but it just hang. :(

```
    $client = new SoapClient("wsdl", array(
                                           'login'    => "...",
                                            'password' => "...",
                                            'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2));
                                            $functions = $client->__getFunctions ();
var_dump ($functions);

$parameters = array("ReqVal" => "nu?");
//$result = $client->__soapCall("GetStr", $parameters);
//$result = $client->GetStr($parameters);
```

Functions returns normaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the [php soapclient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php), you need to use [basicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx), not [wsHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731299.aspx).

For a very simple complete working example, see my [Echo Service](https://github.com/justaprogrammer/EchoService), which includes [a php client](https://github.com/justaprogrammer/EchoService/blob/master/EchoService/EchoClient.php).

This downside of this is that your service will not implement [WS-Reliable Messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-ReliableMessaging) or [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security). However, if you need those, there is an open source party module called the [WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/) that supposedly handles wsHttpBinding.